# uitable reloadData doesnt represent updated database

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a testviewcontroller which contains a UItableview based somewhat on the uitable sqlite tutorial on the net. Question that i have is when i create a new object via the appdelegate which is inserted into the database with no issues the table rows do not get updated. They will only update after the application is restarted.

This is the addNewMessageViewController which displays the form to add new items to the database - its here i would expect that after it adds the item it updates TestViewController's tabledata. Im sure it is being updated but some reason unknown to me it only refreshes the data when the app is started

Comment: You did not seriously just post your entire project...

Comment: LOL at NSPostWhenIdle's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i dont know if its there in your code, but i dont see where you update the `appDelegate.messageArray` when you add a message or edit it. If your not doing that then obviously this is the issue.

Comment: spot on! thanks for that! found that i hadn't used self when adding or removing from the array - fixed now!